# Not able to understand the use of .suffixes rule in makefile ubuntu

Tags: makefile

I have seen various makefiles where they use the `.SUFFIXES` rule. As per my understanding which means, taking a simple example

step1:

```
.SUFFIXES: .o .c .cpp .cc .cxx .C

#where $< indicates the source file and $@ represents the target file.
.cpp.o:
        $(CXX) -c $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"
```

it will compile the target file to a `.o` file using the source with `CXX` compiler.

But after this i also see some other commands like

step2:

```
all: Makefile $(TARGET)
```

Step3:

```
someobjectfile.o: dependencies
```

So, if we can use `.SUFFIXES` rule to compile my target then why to use Step3.
i apologies if it is a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start off by pointing out that suffix rules are [obsolete in GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules)

> *Suffix rules* are the old-fashioned way of defining implicit rules for `make`. Suffix rules are obsolete because pattern rules are more general and clearer. They are supported in GNU `make` for compatibility with old makefiles.

(Although for legacy reasons `.SUFFIXES` still controls which built-in rules will be available.)

That said, just because you've told make that `.o` files can be compiled from sources with certain suffixes does not mean that there aren't any other dependencies beyond the individual source file, the following is extremely common for example

```
someobjectfile.o: someheader.h someotherheader.h
```

Answer (score 1):

`.SUFFIXES` controls [*suffix rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suffix-Rules):

> Suffix rules are the old-fashioned way of defining implicit rules for make. Suffix rules are obsolete because pattern rules are more general and clearer. They are supported in GNU make for compatibility with old makefiles.

In other words, you can ignore `.SUFFIXES` and write your pattern rule as:

```
%.o : %.cpp
```

---

```
someobjectfile.o: dependencies
```

The above adds dependencies of `someobjectfile.o` regardless of how `.o` are made.